# Div element's color changing with no reason

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've created a HTML page that draws squares on screen:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:z-index="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> <!-- For draggable -->

    <script src="exercise.js"></script>
    <script>
        "use strict";

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var numberOfSquares = 5;

        for (var i = 0; i < numberOfSquares; i++)
        {
            var newWidth = getRandomSize();
            var newHeight = getRandomSize();
            var newColor = getRandomColor();
            var newPosition = getRandomPosition(newWidth, newHeight);

            var newSquare = $('<div class="square"><div/>').css({
                'position': 'fixed',
                'top': newPosition[1],
                'left': newPosition[0],
                'width': newWidth,
                'height': newHeight,
                'background-color': newColor
            });

            newSquare.appendTo($("body"));
        }
    });

    </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Where the .js file contains only:

```
function getRandomSize()
{
    var size = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1) + 100;
    return size;
}

function getRandomColor()
{
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ )
    {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
}

function getRandomPosition(objectWidth, objectHeight)
{
    var x = window.innerWidth - objectWidth;
    var y = window.innerHeight - objectHeight;
    var randomX = Math.floor(Math.random() * x);
    var randomY = Math.floor(Math.random() * y);
    return [randomX, randomY];
}
```

The problem is that after creating the page, on clicking at random place, the color of one of the squares is changing for no visible reason. Any ideas why?

Comment: provide fiddle or something pls? http://jsfiddle.net/xBB5x/2511/

Comment: working fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/wdkz5Lgd/

Comment: @JoelAlmeida It works fine but you will see the effect if you open the developer tool for example in chrome. If you do that you will see the color changing of 1 square. EDIT: nope can't reproduce it anymore. Weird. It works.

Comment: @Joel Almeida I'm using IntelliJ 14.1.14 with Chrome JetBrains IDE Support. Maybe the problem is with that?

Comment: @SharonKo can't really say yes. Can't say no. Its a weird rendering bug that probably has to do with something else than your code.

Comment: @Rotan075 you sure you didn't open the developer tool with "inspect element", which will highlight the square you clicked on and "change" color. But that's has nothing to do with the script, it's just chome telling you the element you clicked on.

Comment: Yep that would be probably the case @Esko ;)